# How can I specify how Python's csv.DictWriter handles tuple field values?

Tags: python, csv

I am using [`csv.DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

I'd like to specify how it handles a tuple value in a dictionary. For example:

```
>>> import csv, sys
>>> d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': (1,2)},]
>>> csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, ('a', 'b'))
>>> csv_writer.writerows(d)
1,1
2,"(1, 2)"
```

Instead of:

```
1,1
2,"(1, 2)"
```

I'd like it to be something like:

```
1,1
2,1 2
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to preprocess a copy of the dict into the format you want, making every value a string.  To get rid of the quotes, mess with the `dialect` kwarg to the `DictWriter.__init__`

Comment: alternatively just use a plain old file write, there's nothing particularly magical about `DictWriter`